# Can 2 different wires be connected to the same GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, connection, microphone

I am trying to make a voice assistant with the Raspberry Pi and [ReSpeaker 4-mic array](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_4_Mic_Array_for_Raspberry_Pi/).
ReSpeaker 4-mic array requires 40 pins to be connected to Raspberry Pi. But besides that, I want to connect the On/Off button. And all the problem is here. The On/Off button is using Pin 5(SCL) and Pin 6(GND). So, the question is can I connect the microphone and button together to the same pins(I mean Can I connect the On/Off pin 5 wire and microphone same pin together to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Despite having a 40-pin connector, you probably won't use all of them. If you find any circuit or information on what pins it uses, you can use a different one for the button.

Comment: Sir but there is no any documentation that I can read about.

Comment: @Varuzhan The site that you linked for ReSpeaker provides a wealth of information, including a schematic for the board. The schematic shows you which pins of the 40-pin connector are actually used.